# What is the advantage of Lambda Curry expression in C++?

Tags: c++, lambda

I have learned how to write the following lambda expression in C++ as.

```
auto addCurry = [](auto &a) {
    return [&a](auto &b) {
        return [&a, &b] (auto &c){
            return a+b+c;
        };
    };
};

std::cout << addCurry("how")("are")("you?") << std::cout;
```

I applied the above technique to concatenate string or to sum some numbers. I am wondering why I should refer the above lambda expression over a normal function or a normal in-line string concatenation as following?

```
auto my_function(auto &a, auto &b, auto &c) {
    return a + b + c;
}

std::string a = "aa", b="bb", c = "cc";
std::cout << my_function(a, b, c) << std::endl;

// or just...
std::string my_string = a + b + c;

// or just ...
int i = 1; j = 2; k = 3;
int my_i = i + j + k;
```

What is the advantage of the above lambda expression and when is it useful to apply in C++?

Comment: Most likely, you shouldn't. Why do you think you should?

Comment: Because the online trainer said: prefer lambda expression as a local function of limited use. But he did not say why. That's why I wonder why lambda expression and not just a normal local function.

Comment: C++ doesn't have local functions, that's why.

Answer (score 5):

Currying and partial function application are useful any time you have to invoke a function (typically multiple times) with some of the arguments fixed.

There's even a library providing a facility to curry or partially apply "functions":

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/hana/functional/curry.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace boost::hana;

constexpr auto plus = boost::hana::curry<2>(std::plus<>{});

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4};
    std::ostream_iterator<int> os(std::cout, ",");
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), os, plus(3)); // prints 4,5,6,7,
}
```

---

Clearly you could have made the currying manually, as in your example,

```cpp
constexpr auto plus = [](auto x){
    return [x](auto y){
        return x + y;
    };
};
```

but then you're just reinventing a small wheel named `std::plus<>{}`. Furthermore, you wouldn't be able to call it like `plus(x,y)`, whereas you are if you curry it via `hana::curry`.

You could also just define

```cpp
auto plus3(int x) {
    return x + 3;
}
```

and use

```cpp
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), os, plus3);
```

but where's "code reusability" gone?

---

Imho, getting a feel of the impressive importance of currying and partial function application is something that goes almost by necessity together with embracing at least a bit of functional programming.

Indeed, the purely functional programming language Haskell makes currying the default, in the sense that functions are curried by default:

```hs
twoPlusThree = 2 + 3 -- twoPlusThree is 5 (-- introduces a comment)
plus3 = (+ 3) -- we are applying the function + to just one argument
onePlusThree = plus3 1 -- onePlusThree is 4
```

Comment: "in many situations": can you at least name one ?

Comment: `apply a function repeatedly`? because  I cannot invoke a normal custom function as the fourth parameter of the `std::transorm()`function?

Comment: Yes, @OConnor, but how are you gonna pass to it at the same time `std::plus<>{}` and the number 3?

Comment: Thus, lambda expression is actually to be used as a closure function.

Comment: @OConnor, I don't know what you mean. As you can read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), a lambda _expression_ (i.e. the characters `[…](…){…}`, or `[…]<…>(…){…}` in C++20, or any other valid form shown in the linked) **constructs** a closure, which is **an unnamed function object**. Furthermore, there's no lambda expression at all in the first snippet in my answer.